# Django model enum field creates new migrations every time makemigrations is run, even though unchanged

Tags: python, django, enums

As part of a user preferences model:

```
    DAILY = "d"
    WEEKLY = "w"
    FORTNIGHTLY = "f"
    MONTHLY = "m"
    DISABLE = "x"
    EMAIL_FREQUENCY_CHOICES = {
        (DAILY, 'Daily'),
        (WEEKLY, 'Weekly'),
        (FORTNIGHTLY, 'Fortnightly'),
        (MONTHLY, 'Monthly'),
        (DISABLE, 'Disabled'),
    }
    email_frequency = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=EMAIL_FREQUENCY_CHOICES,
        default=WEEKLY,
    )
```

Every time I run `makemigrations` a new migration file is created for this model, with console output of:

```
- Alter field email_frequency on profile
```

Looking at the migration files, it seems like each migration is a different permutation of the enum dictionary.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EMAIL_FREQUENCY_CHOICES` is defined as a set. It should be a list or tuple.

Comment: this does seem to change anything. It still generates the migrations for me