# Django creates automatic migrations despite no changes being made

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

So this is ultimately rather minor issue, but something that annoys me to no end.

At the moment, one of our Apps keeps creating automatic migrations despite no changes being applied to the model. All these "changes" are applied to the state field of the model. Model is below, alongside the TICKET_STATE. No other field is causing issues, just this one field. I tried deleting database and all migrations, but new migrations are constantly being made, named for example

> 0002_auto_20200103_0834.py

These all follow the same format, `<migration number>_auto_<date>_<time>.py`. I have not found anything related to this and no ohter model or field is causing this. All these migrations contain the same section message:

> - Alter field state on ticket

```
TICKET_STATES = {
    (1, 'Odottaa käsittelyä'),
    (2, 'Käsitellään'),
    (3, 'Vaatii lisäselvitystä'),
    (4, 'Selvitetään'),
    (5, 'Suljettu'),
    (6, 'Peruutettu')
}

class Ticket(models.Model):
    state =  models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=TICKET_STATES)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=9, choices=TICKET_TYPE)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=2, choices=TICKET_PRIORITY)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Uusi tiketti')
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='tickets/attachment', null=True, blank=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    date_closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='tickets_created')
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='tickets_modified')
    closed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='tickets_closed')

    def get_type(self):
        return TYPES_DICT[self.type]

    def get_state(self):
        return STATES_DICT[self.state]

    def get_color(self):
        return STATE_COLORS[self.state]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django model enum field creates new migrations every time makemigrations is run, even though unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244944/django-model-enum-field-creates-new-migrations-every-time-makemigrations-is-run)

Comment: It does actually. Changed it and now it works. Thanks. I tried to search for this but that one never came up.